# Dropdown field - first item should be blank - For more than one field (Sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu, lookup

I was looking for a solution to the problem of getting a blank default when using a lookup in a field in Sharepoint. Kit Menke's solution to "Dropdown field - first item should be blank" question works perfectly for my first field with a lookup. But I can't make it work if have more that one field in the same list where I need to insert a blank for each lookup field (works only for the first field). I tried adding a new "Web Part" and applying the same code to the second field, but doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to add a link to the blog post?

Comment: Here is the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257527/dropdown-field-first-item-should-be-blank/4260112.. Maybe I should make this into a blog post Nat. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow-up to my answer here: [Dropdown field - first item should be blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257527/dropdown-field-first-item-should-be-blank)

Version 2.0 allows you to add the names of your dropdowns to `dropdownNames` in the `MyCustomExecuteFunction` function. As with the first one, this will work only with **required single select lookup fields**. Also, in order to edit the page again and update your Content Editor Web Part you may have to choose a value for your dropdowns otherwise you get the dreaded `An unexpected error has occurred.`. Good luck! :D

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetDropdownByTitle(title) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        if (dropdowns[i].title === title) {
            return dropdowns[i];

        }
    }
    return null;
}

function GetOKButtons() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var len = inputs.length;
    var okButtons = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type && inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() === 'button' && 
             inputs[i].id && inputs[i].id.indexOf('diidIOSaveItem') >= 0) {
             okButtons.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }
    return okButtons;
}

function AddValueToDropdown(oDropdown, text, value, optionnumber){
    var options = oDropdown.options;
    var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    option.setAttribute('value',value);
    if (typeof(optionnumber) == 'number' && options[optionnumber]) {
        oDropdown.insertBefore(option,options[optionnumber]);
    }
    else {
        oDropdown.appendChild(option);
    }
    oDropdown.options.selectedIndex = 0;
}

function WrapClickEvent(element, newFunction) {
    var clickFunc = element.onclick;
    element.onclick = function(event){
        if (newFunction()) {
            clickFunc();
        }
    };
}

function MyCustomExecuteFunction() {
    // **** ADD YOUR REQUIRED SINGLE SELECT FIELDS HERE ***
    var dropdownNames = [
        'Large Lookup Field',
        'My Dropdown Field'
    ];

    var dropdownElements = [];

    for (var d = 0; d < dropdownNames.length; d++) {
        // find the dropdown
        var dropdown = GetDropdownByTitle(dropdownNames[d]);

        // comment this IF block out if you don't want an error displayed
        // when the dropdown can't be found
        if (null === dropdown) {
            alert('Unable to get dropdown named ' + dropdownNames[d]);
            continue;
        }

        AddValueToDropdown(dropdown, '', '', 0);

        // collect all of our dropdowns
        dropdownElements.push(dropdown);
    }


    // add a custom validate function to the page
    var funcValidate = function() {
        var isValid = true;
        var message = "";
        for (var d = 0; d < dropdownElements.length; d++) {
            if (0 === dropdownElements[d].selectedIndex) {
                // require a selection other than the first item (our blank value)
                if (isValid) {
                    isValid = false;
                } else {
                    message += "\n"; // already had one error so we need another line
                }
                message += "Please choose a value for " + dropdownNames[d] + ".";
            }
        }
        if (!isValid) {
            alert(message);
        }
        return isValid;
    };

    var okButtons = GetOKButtons();
    for (var b = 0; b < okButtons.length; b++) {
        WrapClickEvent(okButtons[b], funcValidate);
    }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MyCustomExecuteFunction");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about prepending a null option to the select menu of sharepoint.Like,

```
$('#idOfSelectMenu').prepend('<option value="" selected>(None)</option>');
```

I used this approach and append this code only in the NewForm.aspx because in EditForm.aspx it will override the selected option.